# Radiobuttons are still visible when clicked although code states otherwise?

Tags: android, radio-button, visibility

I want the second radio button to be hidden when the first is clicked and vice aversa . Although the code looks ok, when i run the code they are both visible and none of them turn invisible..
Can anybody suggest how to fix the problem
Here is my code:

```
rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioOne);
rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioReturn);

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View e) { 
        if(rb1.isChecked()) {
            r1 = String.valueOf("You have selected 1 way flight");
            hold.putString("radio1", r1);
            rb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rb2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if(rb2.isChecked()) {
            rb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            r2 = String.valueOf("You have selected a return flight");
            hold.putString("radio2", r2); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you check `rb2` you first hide `rb2`, then make it visible again. Intended?

Comment: My guessing is you have coded the logic inside the submit button's `onClickListener` instead of coding it in RadioButton's `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: Just realised that problem there @Sankar V. Will try put an onClickListener on the radio buttons now

Comment: @SankarV, you should post your comment as an answer, since it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have coded the logic inside the submit Button's `onClickListener` instead of coding it in RadioButton's `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.